# Transpose a 2d list without NumPy to get list back

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matrix, transpose

In python 3 to transpose `matrix = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]` we can do `zip(*matrix)` but this returns an itterable.

So then I did `list(zip(*matrix))` but this is a list wrapped around tuples not list of list.

So I used a map to get `map(list, zip(*matrix))` which returns a map object not a list of lists like the original

Finally I did `list(map(list, zip(*matrix)))` which gave me what I want, but surely there is a faster and cleaner way of doing this without NumPy

Comment: The linked post did not answer my question at all, I read it before posting this one please re open my question.

Comment: How about : `[list(x) for x in zip(*matrix)]`?